# How to use Redhat CloudForms Cinder volumes for Kubernetes PersistentVolumes

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, block-storage

I have deployed a Kubernetes cluster with 3 worker nodes on Redhat Clouldforms platform. The master node and all the worker nodes are deployed within virtual instances created in the Redhat Clouldforms. The Kubernetes cluster has been deployed successfully and also I could be able to deploy an application on top of that.

Now I want to use a PersistentVolume for my application. So, I created a block storage volume in Redhat Clouldforms platform. It says "Openstack cinder manager" as the storage manager. I have not attached the volume to any of worker nodes or master node since it should be accessible from all 3 worker nodes.

1. My question is how to bind my block storage volume with the Kubernetes PersistentVolume. What should I use for the volume type field in the PersistentVolume configuration yaml.
2. What are further configurations needed for the binding